# Boost dependency error when installing MariaDB 10.1

Tags: c++, boost, mariadb

I'm attempting to install MariaDB 10.1 and am getting the following error:

Error: Package: galera-25.3.15-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0()(64bit)

The full output is:

```
$: yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * extras: mirror.us.oneandone.net
 * updates: repos.dfw.quadranet.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.1.14-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-common for package: MariaDB-client-10.1.14-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.1.14-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: galera for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.14-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjemalloc.so.1()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.14-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-common.x86_64 0:10.1.14-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package galera.x86_64 0:25.3.15-1.rhel7.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0()(64bit) for package: galera-25.3.15-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package jemalloc.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: galera-25.3.15-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have this Boost library installed in /usr/local/bin/boostlibs/lib:

```
$: locate libboost | grep program
/usr/local/bin/boost_1_53_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/gcc-4.8.3/release/link-static/threading-multi/libboost_program_options.a
/usr/local/bin/boost_1_53_0/bin.v2/libs/program_options/build/gcc-4.8.3/release/threading-multi/libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0
/usr/local/bin/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/libboost_program_options.a
/usr/local/bin/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/libboost_program_options.so
/usr/local/bin/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0
/usr/local/bin/boostlibs/lib/libboost_program_options.a
/usr/local/bin/boostlibs/lib/libboost_program_options.so
/usr/local/bin/boostlibs/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0
```

I have added this directory to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, in an unsuccessful attempt to resolve this problem:

```html
$: echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64/lksctp-tools:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/bin/boostlibs/lib
```

I will eventually need galera so I need to get this resolved. Any suggestions (that work) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: boost-1.53 is the default version for RHEL 7 / CentOS 7 : # `yum install boost-devel.x86_64` ... http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention this is a CentOS 7 server. I'll try that as soon as I'm able. Thanks, Knud.

Comment: I was able to get all of the boost rpm files I needed from Knud's link and install maradb. Thanks again, Knud.

Comment: I have the same problem with update of MariaDB on CentOS 7.3: `Error: Package: galera-25.3.19-1.rhel6.el6.x86_64 (mariadb) Requires: libboost_program_options.so.5()(64bit)`
boost-devel-1.53.0-26.el7.x86_64 is allready installed from base repo.

Answer (score 1):

boost-1.53 is the default version for RHEL 7 / CentOS 7 : # `yum install boost-devel.x86_64`

Overview http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem.However the cause was I has installed the 32 bit version of libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0 rpm whereas the required one was 64 bit.

After installing the 64 bit one it god resolved and Mariadb was Installed successfully.